# Always resolve certain field references in groq query

Tags: sanity

We have certain type of fields that point to a reference that we want to resolve. Is there a way to search for these fields, however deep down the tree they are, and apply the "->" on it? We have prefixed these field with "msg_".

An example structure might look like this, but could also be buried deeper into another "children" array:

```
"children":[
  0:{
   "_key":"e0baca937bf2"
   "_type":"hero"
   "backgroundImage":{...}
   "msg_subtitle":{
     "_ref":"2459a16f-8d54-4f7a-8a57-31ad6a100d44"
     "_type":"reference"
   }
   "msg_title":{
     "_ref":"91cb61db-029b-4117-8872-154c190f4195"
     "_type":"reference"
   }
}]
```

So we want all the fields starting with "msg_" 's hard reference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can't recursively traverse references in GROQ yet.

Were you thinking about something like [this](https://github.com/sanity-io/GROQ/issues/21)? I'm not exactly sure what you mean by `search`.

That would indeed be handy to have a possibility like that. That said, in many of these cases we have been asked about this before, we have uncovered that it's fine to use the `->` explicitly, and at the same time found content modeling problems.

**The answer to this question is no**, but feel free to reach out in the Community Slack: https://slack.sanity.io/. It may be that we can help you out some more there, and it's easier to have discussions there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Not traverse references really but rather the page tree itself. Something like [that](https://github.com/sanity-io/GROQ/issues/21) is what I'm looking for. By searching I mean to be able to filter out what fields I would want to dereference, for example the fields starting with "msg_". Although, that might not be needed if you would be able to auto-dereference.